# Using mysql length based on length quote

Tags: mysql

I'm creating a html checkbox to filter quotes based on length quote in database.

SHORT (1-10 chars)
MEDIUM (10-20 chars)
LONG (20 - * chars)

Website is loading fast when selecting one checkbox (short)

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (LENGTH(quotes_en.quote) - LENGTH(replace(quotes.quote, ' ', ''))) < 10

full explain

explain SELECT count(quotes.id) OVER() AS num, quotes.id, quotes.bg_image, quotes.author, quotes.active, author_info.author, author_info.proffesions, quotes_nl.quote, quotes_nl.id, sentiment.id FROM author_info Left join quotes ON author_info.author = quotes.author Left Join quotes_nl ON quotes.id = quotes_nl.id left join sentiment on quotes.id = sentiment.id WHERE FIND_IN_SET('novelist', author_info.proffesions) AND quotes.active = 1 AND (LENGTH(quotes_nl.quote) - LENGTH(replace(quotes_nl.quote, ' ', ''))) < 10 ORDER BY quotes.added DESC LIMIT 0, 24



1   SIMPLE  author_info ALL 
    NULL
    
    NULL
    
    NULL
    
    NULL
    47486   Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort    
1   SIMPLE  quotes  ref PRIMARY,author,active   author  402 blackan6_website.author_info.author 10  Using index condition; Using where  
1   SIMPLE  sentiment   eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   blackan6_website.quotes.id  1   Using index 
1   SIMPLE  quotes_nl   eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   blackan6_website.quotes.id  1   Using where
```

When selecting SHORT and LONG, using the OR condition in my query, the website is not loading and get a timeout error.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (LENGTH(quotes_en.quote) - LENGTH(replace(quotes.quote, ' ', ''))) > 10 OR (LENGTH(quotes_en.quote) - LENGTH(replace(quotes.quote, ' ', ''))) > 20
```

full explain

```
explain SELECT count(quotes.id) OVER() AS num, quotes.id, quotes.bg_image, quotes.author, quotes.active, author_info.author, author_info.proffesions, quotes_nl.quote, quotes_nl.id, sentiment.id FROM author_info Left join quotes ON author_info.author = quotes.author Left Join quotes_nl ON quotes.id = quotes_nl.id left join sentiment on quotes.id = sentiment.id WHERE FIND_IN_SET('novelist', author_info.proffesions) AND quotes.active = 1 AND (LENGTH(quotes_nl.quote) - LENGTH(replace(quotes_nl.quote, ' ', ''))) < 10 OR (LENGTH(quotes_nl.quote) - LENGTH(replace(quotes_nl.quote, ' ', ''))) > 20 ORDER BY quotes.added DESC LIMIT 0, 24



    `1` SIMPLE  author_info ALL 
    NULL
    
    NULL
    
    NULL
    
    NULL
    47486   Using temporary; Using filesort 
1   SIMPLE  quotes  ref PRIMARY,author,active   author  402 blackan6_website.author_info.author 10  Using index condition   
1   SIMPLE  sentiment   eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   blackan6_website.quotes.id  1   Using index 
1   SIMPLE  quotes_nl   eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   blackan6_website.quotes.id  1   Using where
```

DATABASE

```
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

CREATE TABLE `quotes_en` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `quote` varchar(350) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

ALTER TABLE `quotes_en`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
COMMIT;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

version
10.3.28-MariaDB-cll-lve

I got 1.2M quotes in the database.

How can i handle this?
Regards

Comment: please edit your question to show (as text, not images) output of `select version;` and `show create table yourtablename;` and `explain SELECT ...rest of your query` for both queries

Comment: note that you are not selecting by number of characters, you are selecting by number of spaces, which is going to be one fewer than the number of words in the quote

Comment: sorry, I meant `select version();` not `select version;`

Comment: If you do `< 20`, you get both SHORT and MEDIUM with only one test.